# Socket watchdog in rx-java

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, reactive-programming, rx-java

I am currently struggling trying to implement a tcp watchdog/retry system using rx, your help will be greatly appreciated.

Having an Observable, I'd like to have an Observable resulting from periodically check whether we still can write to the socket. Easy enough, I can do something like this:

```
class SocketSubscribeFunc implements Observable.OnSubscribeFunc<Socket> {
  private final String hostname;
  private final int port;
  private Socket socket;

  SocketSubscribeFunc(String hostname, int port) {
    this.hostname = hostname;
    this.port = port;
  }

  public Subscription onSubscribe(final Observer<? super Socket> observer) {
    try {
      log.debug("Trying to connect...");
      socket = new Socket(hostname, port);
      observer.onNext(socket);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      observer.onError(e);
    }
    return new Subscription() {
      public void unsubscribe() {
        try {
          socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    };
  }
}

Observable<Socket> socketObservable = Observable.create(new SocketSubscribeFunc(hostname,port));
Observable<Boolean> watchdog = Observable.combineLatest(socketObservable, Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS), new Func2<Socket, Long, Boolean>() {

  public Boolean call(final Socket socket, final Long aLong) {
    try {
      socket.getOutputStream().write("ping\n".getBytes());
      return true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
     return false;
    }
  }
});
```

Now, I want to retry connecting if the socket can be acquired (server/link is down at creation) or becomes unwritable (server/link is unreachable after successful connection).
Ideally by resubscribing to the socket Observable whose OnSubscribeFunc creates the connection using the retry operator.
As you can see this would introduce a circular dependency between the socket and the watchdog Observables.
I toyed for a while with switchMap/materialize... in order to propagate the eventual error to no avail.

I am close to abandon this idea and using Subjects from side-effecting code. But there should be a better way somewhere in the global mind :)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6):

First off, I'd avoid `Observable.create` most of the time as it is usually unneeded and introduces unnecessary complexity. In this case, Rx has an operator called `using` which allows you to create a resource object that exists for the life of the Observable. It catches runtime errors automatically, and also provides a dispose action, so this would be perfect for the socket in this use case. I'm using Java8 lambdas since they're infinitely easier to pseudocode.

```
Observable.using(
    // Resource (socket) factory
    () -> {
      try {
        return new Socket(hostname, port);
      } catch (IOException e) {
        // Rx will propagate this as an onError event.
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
      }
    },
    // Observable factory
    (socket) -> {
      return Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
          .map((unusedTick) {
            try {
              socket.getOutputStream().write("ping\n".getBytes());
              return true;
            } catch (IOException e) {
              throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
          })
          // Retry the inner job up to 3 times before propagating.
          .retry(3);
    },
    // Dispose action for socket.
    // In real life the close probably needs a try/catch.
    (socket) -> socket.close())
    // Retry the outer job up to 3 times.
    .retry(3)
    // If we propagate all errors, emit a 'false', signaling service is not available.
    .onErrorResumeNext(Observable.just(false));
```

Note that this will retry the outer job if the inner one propagates (after 3 failures.) To fix that you should check out the docs on retry with a predicate as well as retryWhen. You could throw a special RuntimeException and only retry the outer job if this isn't the type propagated by the inner job.

`using` docs: http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#using(rx.functions.Func0,%20rx.functions.Func1,%20rx.functions.Action1)